# Possible to specify uneven steps in input[type=range]?

Tags: html

I'd like my `<input type="range">` slider to have a series of unequal increments for the `step` attribute.  Is this possible?  I'd like the values to be 100, 70, 50, 20.  Since there are unequal amounts between these values, setting `step` to a value won't work.  I haven't found any documentation about this, so I'm wondering if anyone might have a solution here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to have an imprecise `step` amount.  According to [the specifications](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.range.html),

> step = "any" or positive floating-point number

Since you can only specify a positive floating-point number (a single number) and `any` is not what you want, you can't do what you want to do with `<input type=range>` alone.

Instead you would have to create a custom widget using JS or otherwise use JS to round to the nearest acceptable values based on the step.