# input range slider with custom steps as an array - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set an array as steps in range slider

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Slider } from 'antd';
const App = () => {
  const customSteps = [0, 25, 50, 75, 100];
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  function handleChange(e) {
    const newValue = e.target.value;
    setValue(newValue);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Slider min={customSteps[0]}
                        max={customSteps[customSteps.length - 1]}
                        step={1}
                        value={value}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        list="tickmarks" />
                      <datalist id="tickmarks">
                        {customSteps.map((step, index) => (
                          <option key={index} value={step} label={step}>
                            {step}
                          </option>
                        ))}
                      </datalist>
    </>
  );
};
```

**open this to understand what i am trying to say**
[1]: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-water-z6fjv?fontsize=14&file=/src/index.js:212-240

Answer (score 0):

The step value is single value and not a list of values, so having different steps is not possible. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149479/6555850

If you are using antd then you can try using the marks option instead for uneven steps. You will have to convert your array to an object instead.

DEMO: https://codesandbox.io/s/fdfwkq?file=/demo.tsx

See the last one where step=null, that should work how you want.